# join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'tuple' -- in Django while making a newspaper projects

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am relatively new to Django and was trying to make a mock newspaper app from django following the 'Django for beginners' book.

I made a CreateView for the articles and routing it for 'new/' in my articles app in the project and setting the correct templates.

Now redirecting to '/new/' leads to this TypeError.

> Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/new/
>
> Django Version:    3.0.6
>
> Exception Type:    TypeError
>
> Exception Value:    join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'tuple'
>
> Exception Location:    c:\users\adi\anaconda3\lib\genericpath.py in _check_arg_types, line 149

========================================================================

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ADI\.virtualenvs\DJANGOdEV-QAaUnZ0o\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\ADI\.virtualenvs\DJANGOdEV-QAaUnZ0o\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\ADI\.virtualenvs\DJANGOdEV-QAaUnZ0o\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Users\ADI\.virtualenvs\DJANGOdEV-QAaUnZ0o\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Users\ADI\.virtualenvs\DJANGOdEV-QAaUnZ0o\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 81, in rendered_content
    template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
  File "C:\Users\ADI\.virtualenvs\DJANGOdEV-QAaUnZ0o\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 63, in resolve_template
    return select_template(template, using=self.using)
  File "C:\Users\ADI\.virtualenvs\DJANGOdEV-QAaUnZ0o\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 42, in select_template
    return engine.get_template(template_name)
  File "C:\Users\ADI\.virtualenvs\DJANGOdEV-QAaUnZ0o\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 34, in get_template
    return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)
  File "C:\Users\ADI\.virtualenvs\DJANGOdEV-QAaUnZ0o\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 143, in get_template
    template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)
  File "C:\Users\ADI\.virtualenvs\DJANGOdEV-QAaUnZ0o\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 125, in find_template
    template = loader.get_template(name, skip=skip)
  File "C:\Users\ADI\.virtualenvs\DJANGOdEV-QAaUnZ0o\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\base.py", line 18, in get_template
    for origin in self.get_template_sources(template_name):
  File "C:\Users\ADI\.virtualenvs\DJANGOdEV-QAaUnZ0o\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\filesystem.py", line 36, in get_template_sources
    name = safe_join(template_dir, template_name)
  File "C:\Users\ADI\.virtualenvs\DJANGOdEV-QAaUnZ0o\lib\site-packages\django\utils\_os.py", line 17, in safe_join
    final_path = abspath(join(base, *paths))
  File "c:\users\adi\anaconda3\lib\ntpath.py", line 115, in join
    genericpath._check_arg_types('join', path, *paths)
  File "c:\users\adi\anaconda3\lib\genericpath.py", line 149, in _check_arg_types
    (funcname, s.__class__.__name__)) from None
```

TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'tuple'

The createView is :

```
class ArticleCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article_new.html',
    fields = ('title', 'body', 'author')
```

and the url routing is:

```
path('new/', ArticleCreateView.as_view(), name='article_new'),
```

Comment: Post the view for the `/articles/new/` endpoint.

Comment: Hey, i have edited the question with the view and url.

Comment: please [edit] the question.

Comment: hey, I tried rewrote most of the settings.py and deleted and made new users and it worked.I don't know what solved it, but the issue is resolved, Thanks anyways. I will look more in the matter and will answer the question myself if i know what was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `,` from `template_name = 'article_new.html',`

The correct View should look like:

```
class ArticleCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article_new.html'
    fields = ('title', 'body', 'author')
```